# How to generate predicted survivor curves from frailty models (using R coxph)?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, frailty

I want to compute predicted survivor function for a Cox proportional hazards
model with frailty terms [using survival package]. It appears that when
frailty terms are in the model, the predicted survivor function cannot be
computed.

```
## Example 
require(survival)
data(rats)

## Create fake weight
set.seed(90989)
rats$weight<-runif(nrow(rats),0.2,0.9)

## Cox model with gamma frailty on litter
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ rx+weight+frailty(litter,dist="gamma"),
data = rats) 

## Compute survival curve from the cox model for rx=0 and weight=0.5 kg
plot(survfit(fit, newdata=data.frame(rx=0,weight=0.5)),xlab = "time",
ylab="Survival") 

## Running this line, I get following error message:
Error in survfit.coxph(fit, newdata = data.frame(rx = 0, weight = 0.5)) : 
Newdata cannot be used when a model has sparse frailty terms
```

I tried using both sparse and non-sparse computation methods by using
`sparse=TRUE, Sparse =FALSE, sparse =0, sparse=5` options. However, none
worked.

How do I compute predicted survivor curve based on my frailty model?

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is the same as would be obtained trying to predict outcomes from a linear mixed effects model. Since the survival curve is non-collapsible, each litter in your example has a litter-specific survival curve according to the model you fit. A frailty as you may know is the same as a random intercept indicating common levels of confounding and prognostic variables endemic to each litter, presumably vis-à-vis genetic traits. Therefore the linear predictor for the hazard ratio is a mix of the observed fixed effects and random litter effects. Unlike mixed models, the Cox model fits the frailty term with penalized regression, the fitted object is of class `coxph-penal` and there is no method for `survreg.coxph-penal`, so the attempts to create the linear predictor fail. There are a couple workarounds.

1. Just fit the marginal model with centered covariates.
2. Center the covariates, fit 1, then fit the random effects model using `coxme` and extract the random effects, add them to the linear predictor with an offset to calculate the stratum specific survival curve for each litter.
3. Perform 2 and marginalize them by averaging all survival curves together, a separate approach to fitting the marginal model.
4. Use fixed effects or strata in a marginal Cox model to predict different survival curves for each litter.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It would be really helpful of you could also include code implementations of these approaches on the same dataset.