# Plot survival curves from a Cox proportional hazard model with shared frailties

Tags: survival, cox-model, frailty

**I am interested in deriving and plotting the survival functions from a Cox proportional hazards model with shared frailties. How can I do this?**

This question has an answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45538/how-to-generate-predicted-survivor-curves-from-frailty-models-using-r-coxph/323637#comment933645_323637), but it is very high level and does not demonstrate a code implementation. I would like to confirm whether the implementation below makes sense. Following the advice [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/6196890), I am asking this follow-up question as a new question, rather than as a comment on the original question.

In this example, I will use the `eortc` dataset from the [coxme](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxme/vignettes/coxme.pdf) package.

Here's a summary of the steps I've taken:

1. Fit two Cox PH models: `fit1` is a marginal model (which has no frailty terms), and `fit2` is a shared frailty model
2. Use the `muhaz` function to get the baseline hazard function from `fit1`
3. Use the random effects from `fit2` as multiples that act on the baseline hazard function, to give the hazard functions of specific groups
4. Derive group-specific cumulative hazard functions by integrating the hazard functions (using `bayestestR::area_under_curve`)
5. Derive group-specific survival curves from the group-specific cumulative hazard functions

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(coxme)
library(ggfortify)
library(muhaz)
library(bayestestR)

data(eortc)

# fit models ------
fit1 <- coxph(Surv(y, uncens) ~ 1, data = eortc)  # marginal model 
fit2 <- coxme(Surv(y, uncens) ~ (1 | center), data = eortc)  # shared frailty model

# estimate baseline hazard using muhaz: ---- 
muhaz_fit <- muhaz(eortc$y, 
                   eortc$uncens, 
                   n.est.grid = 2000, 
                   kern = "rectangle"
)
hazard_base_vector <- muhaz_fit$haz.est
times_vector <- muhaz_fit$est.grid

# df with base hazard:
df_base_haz <- 
  tibble(hazard_base = hazard_base_vector, 
         time = times_vector) %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number())  # used to calculate cumulative hazard 

# df with group-specific hazards: ---- 
# random effects act as multiples on the baseline hazard:
df_random_effect_haz <- 
  df_base_haz %>% 
  mutate(hazard_center1 = hazard_base * exp(ranef(fit2)$center[1]),
     hazard_center2 = hazard_base * exp(ranef(fit2)$center[2]))


# df with derived CHFs, hazards, and survival fns for the RE model: ---- 
# first define functions for getting chf values at time t
calc_chf <- function(index, hazard_colname, df = df_random_effect_haz){
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  df2 <- df %>% dplyr::select(time, {{hazard_colname}}) %>% slice(1:index)
  
  times_vector <- df2[,1]
  haz_vector <- df2[,2]
  return(area_under_curve(times_vector, haz_vector))
}

df_survival <- 
  df_random_effect_haz  %>%  
  mutate(cum_hazard_base = map_dbl(index, calc_chf, hazard_colname = "hazard_base"), 
         cum_hazard_center1 = map_dbl(index, calc_chf, hazard_colname = "hazard_center1"), 
         cum_hazard_center2 = map_dbl(index, calc_chf, hazard_colname = "hazard_center2"), 
         
         surv_base = exp(-cum_hazard_base), 
         surv_center1 = exp(-cum_hazard_center1),
         surv_center2 = exp(-cum_hazard_center2)
  )
  

# plot the derived survival curves: ----
df_survival %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(surv_base, surv_center1, surv_center2), 
               names_to = "survival") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, 
             y = value, 
             group = survival, 
             col = survival)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, max(df_random_effect_haz$time))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the ultimate goal?  What is an example of the events you are modeling?  What made you choose a random effects approach?

Comment: I have data on the time-to-failure of several mechanical components. Each component can be used in different physical contexts. I am thinking of this as a multilevel structure, with the components as the higher level grouping, and the different contexts as the lower level grouping. 

However, each context on its own has a small fraction of all the data for the component, so the estimated survival curves are very noisy. The goal is to get smoother context-specific survival estimates by pooling information across contexts.

Comment: I was largely influenced by this paper: [A tutorial on frailty models](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0962280220921889)

Comment: this does sound like an ideal place for frailty models.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, @FrankHarell. It would be really helpful if you could let me know if you see any issues with the implementation here. One question in particular: perhaps there's no need to work with the hazard functions at all - could I use `survival::basehaz` to get the baseline cumulative hazard function, then just apply the random effect multiples to that, and then derive survival curves?

Comment: The vignettes by Therneau that come with the R `survival` package contain more information about that than I possess.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.